# How to move photos from Picasa albums to Flickr?

Tags: flickr, picasa-web-albums

I am looking for a way to move my Picasa web albums to Flickr? I don't find downloading and uploading very easy.

Is there any website for this purpose?

Comment: You can try [picaflicka](http://www.picaflicka.com/). (I posted this as a comment, since I haven’t used the service.)

Comment: OK, if it helped you, I’ll post it as an answer, maybe it will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [picaflicka](http://www.picaflicka.com/).

> Want to transfer your picasa albums to flickr?
>   Try picaflicka and see the magic!
>   It only takes 3 simple steps and it's free.

<sub>Disclaimer: I haven’t used the service.</sub>